# Can't run multiple commands in command prompt using Python

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt

I'm trying to open the Windows command prompt using Python and then execute a few commands. This is the code I am using:

```
import os

os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k cd C:/ & color 04")
```

Now the command prompt opens and the directory changes to just `C:\>` but the second command to change the color of the text doesn't work and no errors are produced. When I run `cd C:/ & color 04` in the command prompt itself, it works though. So it seems my problem lies with the `&` sign in `cd C:/ & color 4` since the command after the `&` does not execute.

How can I get this feature to work via my Python code (keep in mind I want the command prompt to be visible to the user)?

Comment: Could you use a minimal example of what isn't working the way you expect? E.g.,  does `os.system("date & date")` work or not?

Comment: I tried it now and it only executes once

Comment: ok. could you edit your question and add the more minimal example?

Comment: That's all the code I'm using, I can't make it more minimal than that unfortunately

Comment: i consider `os.system("date & date")` more minimal than `os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k cd C:/ & color 04")`. the desired behavior in former case is much more obvious

Comment: I tried that but then the command prompt isn't visible (just added that note to my question now)

Comment: i'm suggesting you post a minimal example of the problematic behaviour, which in this case is failure of `&` to work correctly in `os.system` calls to the windows command line.  with a minimal example is more likely someone will be able to help you and that your q&a will help someone else.

Comment: `os.system("start \"\" cmd /k \"cd /D C:/ & color 04\"")`

Comment: @JosefZ That worked perfectly! If write it as an answer I can upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right syntax for such [`start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) (typed in an open `cmd` window) is

```
start "" cmd /k "cd /D C:\ & color 04"
```

In Python, [escape](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) inner `"` (double quotes) and `\` (reverse solidus) as follows:

```
import os
os.system("start \"\" cmd /k \"cd /D C:\\ & color 04\"")
```

> The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character.

Read also entire `cmd /?` and `start /?` for further explanation.